# FLASK SQlite Python - Checking if username is already in database

Tags: python, sqlite

Hey can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in my code? I want to check whether an username is already in the database or not.

Whole Route. It wont give me any errors but also wont fill my database.

```
@app.route('/regist', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def regist():
    if request.method == "POST":
        with sql.connect("database.db") as con:
            cur = con.cursor()
        try:
            # flash("register attempted")

            username = request.form['username']
            password = request.form['password']
            passwordencr = request.form['password']
            email = request.form['email']

            x = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ?", (username))

            if int(len(x)) > 0:
                flash("That username is already taken, please choose another")
                return render_template('register.html')
            else:
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (name,password,email) VALUES (?,?,?)",(username,passwordencr,email) )

                con.commit()
                flash ("Successfully registrated")
        except:
            con.rollback()
            msg = "error in insert operation"

        finally:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            session['username'] = username
            gc.collect()
            msg = Message('Hello', sender='yourId@gmail.com', recipients=[email])
            msg.body = "your username for ak047 is: %s and your password is %s" %(username,password)
            mail.send(msg)
            return render_template("home.html", msg=msg)
            con.close()
            gc.collect()
```

Comment: I think your code definitely errors, you should never use a blanket except as you have, if you didn't you would have seen your error

Comment: You don't need to call `int(len(x))`. `len` returns an integer. You also don't need to compare the length of something to 0. `if len(x) > 0` is the same as `if x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I think I have a working code sample for the original problem. However, I think you can solve this duplicate user problem better using constraints within the database. See the bottom of my answer.

First let's check the current code. There are a couple of issues I can see here:

1. Incorrect indent for `try/finally` means there's no connection active during the `try/finally`.
2. The way you're checking for whether there's an entry with the username isn't correct.

*Indent*

In the current code, the `try/finally` block at line 6 needs to be indented one further in order to be able to use the connection established by the connection made in the `with` statement on line 4.

As the code currently stands, the connection will have been closed by the time it's used, so all database access will fail.

*Checking for a user*

The code used to check for a user will fail, throwing an exception which will cause the finally to be hit and the `rollback` to be executed. The return value from `execute` throws an exception when you call `len`, whether or not there are any entries.

Here's what I get from a python shell to show what I mean:

```
>>> int(len(cur.execute("select * from people where name_last=:who", {"who": "mike"})))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'sqlite3.Cursor' has no len()
```

Instead, to check whether a `select` statement returns a value, use `fetchone` and see if it returns `None`:

```
# No users named `fred`:
>>> cur.execute("select * from people where name_last=:who", {"who": "fred"}) 
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10bbd0180>
>>> cur.fetchone() is None
True

# At least one user named `mike`:
>>> cur.execute("select * from people where name_last=:who", {"who": "mike"})
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10bbd0180>
>>> cur.fetchone() is None
False
```

I think therefore something like this might work:

```
def regist():
    if request.method == "POST":
        with sql.connect("database.db") as con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            try:
                # ... Collecting form info ...

                cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ?", (username))

                if cur.fetchone() is not None:
                    flash("That username is already taken...")
                    return render_template('register.html')
                else:
                    cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (name,password,email) VALUES (?,?,?)",(username,passwordencr,email) )
                    con.commit()
                    flash (...)
             except:
                 con.rollback()

             finally:
                 session['logged_in'] = True
                 session['username'] = username
                 # ... mailing code ...
```

**Alternative approach**

A more robust approach would be to let the database take responsibility for preventing duplicate users.

Make the `name` column `unique` when creating the table. Then inserting a record with the same username will throw an exception. Taking an example from the [sqlite3 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager):

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.execute("create table person (id integer primary key, firstname varchar unique)")

# Successful, con.commit() is called automatically afterwards
with con:
    con.execute("insert into person(firstname) values (?)", ("Joe",))

# con.rollback() is called after the with block finishes with an exception, the
# exception is still raised and must be caught
try:
    with con:
        con.execute("insert into person(firstname) values (?)", ("Joe",))
except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
    print "couldn't add Joe twice"
```

Comment: Updated code to hopefully make it clear what I was saying :)

Comment: It still won't fill my database. What I was trying to say: When I remove the piece where it checks for the username in the DB(If its already there), my code works perfectly and it fills my db..

Comment: Is there a way I could get in touch with you via a chat? Maybe an IRC or something?

Comment: I've made my name row now unique. so It will automatically get into the except: when it notices that the username is already in that DB?

Comment: That's what the docs state and what happens in my testing. I'm assuming you mean name _column_ not name _row_.

Comment: Another Question: It doesnt add multiple usernames in my DB but now I have the bug in my code, that when I use a username that already exists, it logs me in anyways...

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you there -- we've solved the username issue I think, so you'll need to play for a bit to see what's going on there (and ask another question on SO if need be).

Answer (score 1):

Make one function, who check username and email is already in database or not.

```
#Models
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now())
    updated_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now(), server_onupdate=db.func.now())
    tasks = db.relationship('Task', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

    @classmethod
    def is_user_name_taken(cls, username):
      return db.session.query(db.exists().where(User.username==username)).scalar()

    @classmethod
    def is_email_taken(cls, email):
      return db.session.query(db.exists().where(User.email==email)).scalar()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.username)

#User Signup Api
@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/signup', methods=['POST'])
def signup():

    if 'username' not in request.json:
        return jsonify({'username': 'must include username'})
    if 'email' not in request.json:
        return jsonify({'email': 'must include email'})
    if 'password' not in request.json:
        return jsonify({'password' : 'must include password' })

    if User.is_user_name_taken(request.json['username']):
         return jsonify({'username': 'This username is already taken!'}), 409
    if User.is_email_taken(request.json['email']):
         return jsonify({'email': 'This email is already taken!'}), 409

    if request.json :
        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(request.json['password'], method='sha256')
        new_user = User(username=request.json['username'], email=request.json['email'], password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({'user': 'user created successfully'}), 201
    return jsonify({'username': 'must include username', 
            'password': 'must include password', 
            'email' : 'must include email' })
```

Answer (score 0):

this code connects to `database.db` twice at lines 1 and 9. Probably this is not what was initially intended

Comment: It doesn't give me any errors, but the information still wont get passed in the database.

Comment: I've put my code on the top. Would be kind if you can have a look into it.

Comment: I think @Mike Rhodes is right, try/except block should be indented one more level